# Getting the value of the selected item in a Databound combobox

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

I am trying to get the value of the selected item of a combo box in vb to save into a database but it is giving me the following error

> incorrect integer value 'System.Data.DataRowView' for column class at
>   row1

Here is part of my code

```vb
Dim Query As String
Query = "INSERT INTO smartaccounts.basic_fee (class, term, amount) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"
command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
command.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("class", CType(CmbClass.SelectedItem.ToString, String)))
command.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("term", CType(CmbTerm.SelectedItem.ToString, String)))
command.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("amount", CType(TxtAmount.Text, String)))
```

I am rather new to Vb and I guess I must be doing something wrong
What could it be and how can I solve it?

This is how I have passed data to the comboboxes

```
     Private Sub Fees_settings_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter()
    Dim adapter1 As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim ds1 As New DataSet
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server='" & My.Settings.MServer & "';user='" & My.Settings.MDbUser & "';password='" & My.Settings.MDbPass & "';database='" & My.Settings.MDb & "'"
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT name,label FROM classes "
    Dim sql1 As String = "SELECT name,label FROM term"
    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        command1 = New MySqlCommand(sql, MysqlConn)
        command2 = New MySqlCommand(sql1, MysqlConn)
        adapter.SelectCommand = command1
        adapter1.SelectCommand = command2
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        adapter1.Fill(ds1)
        adapter.Dispose()
        adapter1.Dispose()
        command1.Dispose()
        command2.Dispose()
        MysqlConn.Close()
        CmbClass.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        CmbClass.ValueMember = "label"
        CmbClass.DisplayMember = "name"
        CmbTerm.DataSource = ds1.Tables(0)
        CmbTerm.ValueMember = "label"
        CmbTerm.DisplayMember = "name"
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You dont show or explain how data gets into the CBO, but from the error it appears to be data bound.  In that case use `SelectedValue`.  Its probably a bad idea to store an "amount" as string

Comment: I have edited to add that

Comment: CmbClass and CmbTerm are ComboBox objects right?

Comment: Yes they are ComboBoxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `.SelectedItem.ToString` with `.SelectedValue.ToString`.

This is because the former returns the entire `DataRow` while the latter returns only the selected value that is bound to the selected item.

Your code should now look like this:

```vb
Dim Query As String
Query = "INSERT INTO smartaccounts.basic_fee (class, term, amount) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"
command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
command.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("class", CType(CmbClass.SelectedValue.ToString, String)))
command.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("term", CType(CmbTerm.SelectedValue.ToString, String)))
command.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("amount", CType(TxtAmount.Text, String)))
```